# HTTP Get request with object in body

Tags: angular, rest, rxjs

can you help me, i need to send a Center object in the body of the Get request and receive a WorkFlowDC object in return.

I don't know how I can write the method in the service file.

is there anyone who can help me solve this problem and thanks in advance.

```
  findWorkflowDCByCentre(centre: Centre): WorkFlowDC {
    if (this.jwtToken == null) { this.loadToken(); }
    if (this.jwtHelper.isTokenExpired(this.jwtToken)) { this.addToken(); }

    return this.httpClient.get<WorkFlowDC>(this.apiUrl + '/findWorkflowDCByCentre', centre,
      {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'authorization': this.jwtToken })
      }
    );

  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The HTTP specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.1) doesn't describe how GET requests with bodies should be handled so you **shouldn't** do this.

> A payload within a GET request message has no defined semantics;
> sending a payload body on a GET request might cause some existing
> implementations to reject the request.

Browser APIs for making HTTP requests (`fetch` and `XMLHttpRequest`) don't support bodies on GET requests so you **can't** do this directly from Angular (you'd need to go through a server-side proxy).

---

Change the API so that it doesn't expect data in the body of a GET request.